# Magento 2 : Display multiple grids in admin area

Tags: module, grid, magento2.1.0, di.xml

I have displayed my one custom table in a grid format. Now, I want to display one other custom table in a grid format (Under different menu). But I am little bit confused, how to add code in `di.xml` file

Here is my `di.xml` which I have created for my first grid : 
**app/code/Ved/Mymodule/etc/di.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ved_zipcodes</argument> <!-- here ved_zipcodes this is the db table name -->
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News</argument> <!-- Path -->
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- Here name value, we will use in mymodule_my_grid.xml layout file -->
                <item name="mymodule_news_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News\Collection</item> <!-- Collection path -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**How should I update my `di.xml` for displaying second grid in admin using the same custom module?**

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you got any solution?

Comment: No, I did not get. Let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 1):

To add second grid in same module you have to add collection data of second grid as second item of `CollectionFactory` node's `collections` argument.
So in your case `CollectionFactory`  will look like this -

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- Here name value, we will use in mymodule_my_grid.xml layout file -->
                <item name="mymodule_news_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News\Collection</item> <!-- Collection path -->
                <item name="mymodule_secondmodel_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\SecondModel\Collection</item> <!-- Collection path added for second grid -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

The other nodes in the `di.xml` can be repeated for the second grid with change in `unique_name` for nodes (e.g - FilterPool, DataProvider, SerarchResult nodes) ,`listing_file_name`, `Collection` and `ResourceModel` path respectively different for each grid.

Here is the example of my `di.xml` having two grid -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- This nodes below are for first grid -->
    <virtualType name="firstGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool"> <!-- here firstGridFilterPool is unique name for filterpool node and it is later user as Dataprovider node's filerPool argument's value -->
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="FirstGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"> <!-- here FirstGridDataProvider is unique name for Dataprovider node  -->
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\FirstGridModel\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">firstGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="first_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\FirstGridModel\Grid\Collection</item> <!-- Add Collection data for First Grid -->
                <item name="second_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\SecondGridModel\Grid\Collection</item> <!-- Add Collection data for Second Grid -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
     <virtualType name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\FirstGridModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">first_grid_tablename</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\FirstGridModel</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

<!-- This nodes below are repeated for Second grid -->
    <virtualType name="SecondGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool"> <!-- here SecondGridFilterPool is unique name for filterpool node and it is later user as Dataprovider node's filerPool argument's value -->
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="SecondGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"> <!-- here SecondGridDataProvider is unique name for Dataprovider node  -->
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\SecondGridModel\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">SecondGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

     <virtualType name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\SecondGridModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">second_grid_tablename</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\SecondGridModel</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this by following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="first_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\First\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="second_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Second\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- First -->
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\First\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">first_table_name</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\First</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <!-- Second -->
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Second\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">second_table_name</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Second</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Hope it helps.